# Add median trend line and p-value for one-sided repeated measures test in 2-y axis scatter plot [R]

Tags: r

Load sample data frame

```
df <- structure(list(ID = c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3), 
time = c(0L,1L,2L,0L,1L,2L,0L,1L,2L),
M1a = c(0, 0.2, 0.3, 0, 1.5, 2.9,0, 2.4, 3.9), 
M2a = c(0, 0.4, 0.6,0,0.9, 0.9,0,0.5, 0.7), 
M3a = c(0,0.3, 0.4, 0, 0.6, 0.9,0, 0.5, 0.8), 
M4a = c(0,0.6, 0.6,0, 0.4, 0.6,0, 0.2, 0.9), 
M1b = c(0L, 200L, 300L,0L, 300L, 900L,0L, 900L, 1000L), 
M2b = c(0L, 400L, 600L,0L, 600L, 900L,0L, 600L, 1000L), 
M3b = c(0L, 300L, 400L,0L, 200L, 800L,0L, 200L, 900L), 
M4b = c(0L, 600L, 600L,0L, 800L, 1000L,0L, 400L, 1100L)), 
.Names = c("ID", "time", "M1a", "M2a", "M3a", "M4a","M1b", "M2b","M3b", "M4b"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -9L))
```

Now plot two y-axis scatter plot

```
par(mar=c(5,4,4,5)+.1)
plot(df$time,df$M1a,type="p",col="red", main="M1", cex=0.5, cex.main=2, cex.lab=1.0, cex.axis=0.7)
par(new = TRUE)
plot(df$time,df$M1b,type="p",col="blue",xaxt="n",yaxt="n",xlab="",ylab="")
mtext("Relative change (%)",side=4,line=3)
axis(4)
legend("topleft",col=c("red","blue"),lty=1,legend=c("Absolute Change","Relative Change"))
```

## What I am stuck with?

## 1.Median trend line

I was able to add regression line, but I want to have a median trend line connecting M1a and M1b medians for three time points.

## 2.Adding p-values to the plot, repeated one-way anova test

```
fit1=aov(df$M1a~df$time + Error(ID/time),na.action=na.exclude,data=df);
sig1= summary(fit1)$"Error: Within"$"Pr(>F)"
if (sig<0.001) star='**' else if (sig>=0.001&sig<0.05) star='*' else star='';
if (sig1<0.001) star='**' else star='';
```

I was planning to add use above code for adding p-value in my 2-y axis plot. Here, I get sig1 as NULL, however, sig1 should print out 0.153.

The final results should include * mark on the main title of plot (M1), if results are significant.

Any tips? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer #2 first, one needs to look at the inner structures of a summary.aov object:

```
dput(summary(fit1))
structure(list(`Error: ID` = structure(list(structure(list(Df = 1, 
    `Sum Sq` = 5.60666666666667, `Mean Sq` = 5.60666666666667, 
    `F value` = NA_real_, `Pr(>F)` = NA_real_), .Names = c("Df", 
"Sum Sq", "Mean Sq", "F value", "Pr(>F)"), class = c("anova", 
"data.frame"), row.names = "Residuals")), class = c("summary.aov", 
"listof")), `Error: ID:time` = structure(list(structure(list(
    Df = 1, `Sum Sq` = 11.3157142857143, `Mean Sq` = 11.3157142857143), .Names = c("Df", 
"Sum Sq", "Mean Sq"), class = c("anova", "data.frame"), row.names = "df$time")), class = c("summary.aov", 
"listof")), `Error: Within` = structure(list(structure(list(Df = c(1, 
5), `Sum Sq` = c(0.325952380952381, 0.573888888888889), `Mean Sq` = c(0.325952380952381, 
0.114777777777778), `F value` = c(2.83985617480293, NA), `Pr(>F)` = c(0.152766396924706, 
NA)), .Names = c("Df", "Sum Sq", "Mean Sq", "F value", "Pr(>F)"
), class = c("anova", "data.frame"), row.names = c("df$time  ", 
"Residuals"))), class = c("summary.aov", "listof"))), .Names = c("Error: ID", 
"Error: ID:time", "Error: Within"), class = "summary.aovlist")
```

And note that the values within `summary(fit1)$"Error: Within"` are actually buried one level deeper (and don't have names so need numeric index. Do this:

```
summary(fit1)$"Error: Within"[[1]]$`Pr(>F)`
[1] 0.1527664        NA
```

Now to see if I can figure out the two-0rdinate plot issue. Pretty sure one would need to do any median plotting *before* the `par(new=TRUE)` operation because that changes the user coordinate system based on the new data.

Adding a title with extracted value to your plot augmented by the helpful comment by @VincentBonhomme:

```
 plot(df$time,df$M1a,type="p",col="red", cex=0.5, cex.main=2, cex.lab=1.0, cex.axis=0.7)
lines(unique(df$time), 
        tapply(df$M1a, df$time, median)) 
par(new = TRUE) 
plot( df$time, df$M1b,type="p", col="blue", xaxt="n", yaxt="n", xlab="",ylab="") 
lines(unique(df$time), 
      tapply(df$M1b, df$time, median))
mtext("Relative change (%)",side=4,line=3)
axis(4)
legend("topleft",col=c("red","blue"), lty=1,legend=c("Absolute Change","Relative Change"))

title(main=bquote("P-value for M1 (absolute scale)"== 
                       .(round(summary(fit1)$"Error: Within"[[1]]$`Pr(>F)`, 3) ) )  )
```

[image]

Comment: you're right about the `par(new=TRUE)`, this seems to work: `plot(df$time,df$M1a,type="p",col="red", cex=0.5, cex.main=2,     cex.lab=1.0, cex.axis=0.7)`
`lines(unique(df$time), tapply(df$M1a, df$time, median))`
`par(new = TRUE)`
`plot(df$time,df$M1b,type="p",col="blue",xaxt="n",yaxt="n",xlab="",ylab="")
    lines(unique(df$time), tapply(df$M1b, df$time, median))`

Comment: Usually one would want to set the ylim in each based on the joint range of the values, but here the goal is quite different. Two ordinate plots are severely criticized as having great potential for distorting relationships.

Comment: The quantreg package provide a quantil regression. `library(quantreg); abline(rq(M1b~time,data = df,tau = 0.5,col=2)`. Here using the 50% quantil (tau) for the estimation.

Comment: @VincentBonhomme - Thanks. I tried your script for sample df and it worked successfully, but it does not work for my big data. Later mimics sample df structure and your script ran smoothly without any error/warning, but I do not see a median trend line there, actually no change, wonder why?

Comment: @42- Thanks! Your tip was good to go, this code gets the p-value: `sig1= summary(fit1)$"Error: Within"[[1]]$`Pr(>F)`[[1]]`. 

I do not want to explicitly mention the p-value in the title, but only ** or * signs, so that they denote level of significant ** for sig1<0.001 and * sig1>=0.001&sig<0.05 and " " for sig1>0.05, i.e. the title would be either M1** or M1* or M1. Rationale - to keep the plots tidy and symmetrical as I might run it for 300 independent variables. Looking forward!

Comment: @VincentBonhomme - Hi, I tried `J=lines(unique(df$time), 
        tapply(df$M1a, df$time, median))` for my big data and sample df, and followed by `J`, for both datas, J return NULL output.

Comment: just `lines` not `J= ...`

Comment: If there are NA's in your data, then na.rm=TRUE needs to be added to the arguments given to `tapply`.